# how to draw a black rectangle over Image icon?

Tags: java, image, graphics

in my application I have a cross road picture in the background and I want to draw traffic lights on the top of it (black rectangle with 3 circles)
The problem is, I cannot see the rectangle at all, as if it was under the image or something. And if I switch the order in which the items are painted, I get all black image.

Do you have any idea how this can be solved?I am new to graphics and searched similar questions, but none helped me.
Thank you.

```
public MainFrame() throws HeadlessException {
    super("semafor");        
    crossroad = new ImageIcon("cross.png");

    initFrame();
    initComponents();

    sem1 = new Semafor(true, 100, 100);
    add(sem1);

    repaint();
    setVisible(true);
}

//here I paint the image
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(crossroad.getImage(), 0, 45, this);

}

//and in class Semafor i paint the actual traffic lights

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.darkGray);

    //and then the circles
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The first thing I'm noticing is that you are calling `<unknown>.getWidth()` and `<unknown>.getHeight()` for the rectangle size. If it's covering the entire image, this suggests that it is getting that width and height from the panel it is being drawn on.

A simple stack trace,

```
(new Exception).printStackTrace();
```

or

```
Thread.dumpStack();
```

will tell you as much. You could also query the width and height with a `System.out` call to verify that you're getting the values you're expecting, or, if this really gets out of control, learn to use JUnit and the `assert` statement. Honestly, though, it looks like you're just accidentally calling the wrong method.